# Special case of Fisher Z for comparing two correlations

Tags: correlation, intervention-analysis, fisher-transform

I'm a statistical consultant, one of my clients requested something I haven't heard of before: She wants to compare the correlation between X and Y (two ratio scaled variables) before an intervention, to the correlation between X and Y (the same variables) after the intervention.

Usually I would use Fisher's Z (link included [here](http://vassarstats.net/rdiff.html)) and have been done with it, BUT - those aren't two different groups, but one - the same subjects responded to the first X and  to Y (before the intervention), and second X and Y (after the intervention).

Is there a special kind of Fisher Z test for this situation?

Thanks,
Nimrod

P.S.
Just to make it a bit more complicated there are four groups in the research and I would need to do it for every one it separately.